# overriding parent ng-click in child element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

This is a pretty simple question. I have a list with icons on each list element, when I click the actual list element I want to call one function, when I click the icon I want to call another function. Currently when I click the icon it is calling both functions.

e.g
`<li ng-click="ctrl.foo()"><i ng-click="ctrl.bar()"></i><li>`

currently calls ctrl.foo() and ctrl.bar() when it should just call ctrl.bar().

Comment: Why not add the `ng-click` to the parent wrapper element? I don't see why you have to add it the the `<i>`child element. Something like this : `e.g <li ng-click="ctrl.bar()"><i></i><li>`

Comment: You can add the $event variable to the child element function and make use of its method stopPropagation.

Comment: If you're using jQuery then you can use `e.preventdefault`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give ng-click attribute to <li> element, it applies to all elements inside it. If you want to something like text-icon and separate their functions, you can use something like that

```
<li><span ng-click="foo()">Text</span> <i ng-click="bar()"></i> </li>
```